# Calling method after clicked outside of HTML input, Angular2

Tags: html, angular, dom, angular2-forms

I have input in my template like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="object.LanguageTableData" [formControl]="editControl" />
```

"object" is something generated by *ngFor, so I have input with some value, which is "object.LanguageTableData". When I changed the input and click outside of this input (or press enter) I need to call my method (this method will insert - if input value is empty, or update the value in database). I know, that I can call on editControl (type of FormControl) some valueChanges with debounceTime, but I need to call the statement after edit of input is completed - it is when user click outside of the input or press enter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind your code to ButtonPress and OnBlur input events.

Comment: thank you, solved like this <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="object.LanguageTableData" (blur)="mymethod()" (keyup.enter)="mymethod()" />